# Tkinter Text-Widget , scroll to specific line to make it first visible line

Tags: python, tkinter, text-widget

How to scroll to a specific line of text so it becomes  the first visible line in text-widget with coordinates "@0,0".

For instanse I got 100 lines in text widget and curently I got visivle lines 1 to 20 . I want to move line 15 (to scroll to line 15) to the first position without mouse-scrolling .
I know we can do `text_widget.see("15.0")` but it won't move it to the first postion if line 15 is already visible on the screen.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to do that in every possible situation - for example, if the widget is tall enough to make all the lines visible, you aren't going to be able to scroll it at all.  Alternative idea: apply a tag to the line, with a subtly different background color, to call the user's attention to it, regardless of where exactly it ended up after the `.see()`.

Comment: I will add several empty lines so I can always scroll to the last line to make it first visible. But i can't figure out  how to place any line to the first postion if this line is already on the screen.

Comment: `.see("end")` followed by `.see("15.0")` might work in that situation, although I think you'd have to have about two screenfulls of blank lines to guarantee it works.

Comment: That's a good idea as a work around. It will be just one empty line in the end with embeded window to make it high.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

```
text_widget.see("15.0")
lineinfo=text_widget.dlineinfo("15.0")
text_widget.yview_scroll(lineinfo[1], 'pixels' )
```